# How to get an alert when someone changed a word/excel document which is stored on a onedrive

Tags: onedrive

I created a word document and shared it with a bunch of colleagues. 
Can I get an alert

- when someone views the document?
- when someone changed the document`?

Thanks for any tip
Best regards
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

You can get a notification when files you have shared are edited.

This is the default option. You may verify it by:

- Right-click the OneDrive icon in the traybar and choose *Settings*
- Go to the tab "Settings"
- Under "Notifications", check if the following is checked:
  "Display notifications when people share with me or edit my shared files"
- If unchecked, check it and click OK.

[image]